# pam_auth_radius - RADIUS users vs unix users

Tags: authentication, pam, radius, passwd, freeradius2

I have recently set up a server with [FreeRADIUS](http://freeradius.org/) to authenticate and keep track of admin logins on some of my devices.

I'm looking at getting my Linux and FreeBSD  machines authenticating against RADIUS using the pam_auth_radius module. I am currently working with an Ubuntu 10.04 virtual machine for testing. Also I am currently testing with RADIUS authenticating only remote SSH users, I would like ALL authentication to be done this way at some point.

As per instructions from all around the web, I install [pam_auth_radius](http://freeradius.org/pam_radius_auth/) and add a line referencing the module in /etc/pam.d/sshd and added my server address and shared secret to /etc/pam_radius_auth.conf.

After doing this I can authenticate against RADIUS...however, only users that I have added to the test machine (using adduser) can authenticate. For example, user "cory" is a valid RADIUS user, for which the RADIUS returns "Accept", but I keep getting "Permission Denied" while trying to log in via ssh until I "adduser cory".

Do I need to add each and every admin user to each and every server? I realize I can make un-passworded users, so it isn't really a security issue, but it just seems to defeat the point of having a central authentication server if I still have to do account management on each device.

Is there a way to create a temporary user/directory/etc dynamically? Or can users authenticating via RADIUS be mapped to an existing account to remove the need to create each user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's going on is that without the rest of the structures required, the linux system doesn't have any information about user 'cory'.  Things like UID/GID, shell, homedirectory, whatever.

You can set up the local user account, then tell PAM to check for a valid password against RADIUS.

What you really want to do is set up LDAP.  This will let you define complete Unix user accounts in a central database.  Then you would configure your RADIUS server to do validations against the LDAP database for those devices which can use it.

Comment: I do have LDAP functioning as the backend to my RADIUS server. In fact, its the same LDAP directory I use for samba authentication, so the users are type "posixAccount" with a "homeDirectory" and "loginShell". Seems like most of the info that would be needed is there, however I would I no idea where to go next as far as configuring RADIUS/LDAP. Currently I just "Auth-type := Accept" the group I want and "Auth-type := reject" others. Is there anywhere I can look at an example of the type of setup you are referring to?